# Dependency Injection C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dependency-injection

So recently I started learning some design patterns. I stuck at Dependency Injection. After few hours of trying to understand it I wrote some code. Could you tell me if this code represents pattern Dependency Injection? If not please let me now what I have to change there.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class ICar
    {
    public:
        virtual string drive () = 0;
    };
class Audi : public ICar
{
    public:
        string drive () override
        {
            return "I drive Audi";
        }
};
class VW : public ICar
{
    public:
        string drive () override
        {
            return "I drive VW";
        }
};
void displayInfo (ICar& icar)
{
    cout << icar.drive () << endl;
}
int main ()
{
  VW v1;
  displayInfo (v1);
}
```

Thanks for help :)
// edit
So I considered all suggestions and wrote something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class IEngine
{
    public:
    virtual void engineCapacity () = 0;
};
class EngineTDI : public IEngine
{
    public:
    void engineCapacity () override
    {
        cout << "Capacity : 2.0" << endl;
    }
};
class Car
{
    private:
        IEngine* i1;
    public:
    Car (IEngine* i1)
    {
        this -> i1 = i1;
    }
    void engineCapacity ()
    {
         i1 -> engineCapacity ();
    }
};
int main ()
{
    IEngine* i1 = new EngineTDI;
    Car* c1 = new Car (i1);
    c1 -> engineCapacity ();
```

}
Is it now dependency injection?

Comment: Seems to display polymorphism (which is a design pattern) not dependency injection.

Comment: For dependency injection you need two classes, one to depend on the other. For example a Car class might depend upon an Engine class. At it's most basic a reference to an engine object is passed to the car object when the car object is constructed, rather than the car object creating it's own engine object. This is dependency injection (but it can get a lot fancier than that).

Comment: And no doubt some will fundamentally disagree with my definition. The same words can mean different things to different people.

Comment: I would not consider polymorphism a design pattern.

Comment: There's so much technical information to be learned about C++, the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, that playing Buzzword Bingo is just wasting time...

Comment: If you use `template <typename Engine> class Car { ... }` you have compile time injection and don't need a common base class.